# Make a multi-line javascript debugger request to a webpage in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to make a multi-line javascript debbuger call to a webpage here's the code that did not: work

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript("
          function stuff() {
              stuff
          }
    ");
  });
```

Comment: _that did not work_, what did not worked? What error are you getting? what is happening that should not ? what is not happening, that should ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backticks instead of quotes and you'll be good to go. Keep in mind that you're not actually running your function `stuff` though, you're only declaring it.

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`  // Use backticks, not quotes
          function stuff() {
              stuff
          }
          // Optionally, run stuff() here
    `); // Use backticks, not quotes
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It kinda works but when I try this it does not like it

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        function login(token) {
            setInterval(() => {
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${token}"`
            }, 50);
            setTimeout(() => {
            location.reload();
            }, 2500);
            };
            `);
      });
```

Comment: The error says Iframe and Token do not exist. When they do in the websites code

Comment: So to Simplify It I made a electron app that launches https://www.discord.com/login and runs a js script to login using a token. The script that I'm using works in debugger but not in electron.

Comment: Works in the browser debugger? I think that the issue you're seeing is likely related to the specific thing you're trying to accomplish and I'm not really sure enough of the context to know why. I'd advise making a new question detailing exactly what you're doing and exactly what's happening, because you'll be more likely to get the attention of people with  the relevant knowledge. I only really know about the Electron side of things, but know nothing about Discord.